# Does vite-plugin-static-copy work in dev mode?

Tags: vite

I am using vite and would like to move some static assets by using vite-plugin-static-copy. I'm having trouble. When I build the code, I see that the assets are copied to the proper location. However, when I run dev, the assets can't be found either by looking in chrome nor by fetching them.

Does vite-plugin-static-copy copy assets in dev mode?